# Have an annotation imply method parameter usage

Tags: java, intellij-idea

For example:

```
@ConsumesParam
public void method( @TheParam String param ) {
  // doesn't use param
}
```

The IDE flags up `param` as an unused parameter, whereas `@ConsumesParam`, combined with `@TheParam`, does actually cause it to be used. I can add `@SuppressWarnings( "unused" )`, but this is a pattern we're using in many places. Is there something I can add to `@ConsumesParam` to tell the IDE not to flag this up?

The actual situation:

We have rest-controller methods annotated by `@Secured`. We have an aspect which intercepts calls to these methods, and looks for a parameter annotated by `@RequestHeader( name = "X-Api-Key" )`. This means we get authorisation simply by adding the `@Secured` annotation, but it does require adding the parameter to the method signature.

Answer (score 0):

You can add entry points for inspection in "Preferences | Editor | Inspections | Java | Declaration redundancy | Unused declaration":

[image]

Comment: Great, this turned out to be useful elsewhere!
Unfortunately I don't think this solves the original problem. I don't want to say that anything annotated by RequestHeader is an entry point. I want to say that a parameter annoted RequestHeader( name = "X-Api-Key" ) is an entry point in methods annotated by Secured.
I see this "Code patterns..." button, but not sure how to use it. Could that be a way?

Comment: @JamesStevenson you can see an example here https://shorturl.at/aoHKX (for Java it will differ that it has a subclass option) but it doesn't seem to be exactly what you are looking for. You can also check discussion in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-232239 for a possible workaround with annotations